# rkhunter gives me a warning for "/usr/bin/lwp-request" - what should I do? [Debian 9]

Tags: debian, security, rkhunter

So I just installed and ran *rkhunter* which shows me green OKs / Not founds for everything except for: **/usr/bin/lwp-request**, like so:

```
/usr/bin/lwp-request                                     [ Warning ]
```

In the log it says:

```
Warning: The command '/usr/bin/lwp-request' has been replaced by a 
   script: /usr/bin/lwp-request: Perl script text executable
```

I already ran `rkhunter --propupd` and `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` which didn't help. I installed Debian 9.0 just a few days ago and am a newcomer to Linux.

Any suggestions on what to do?

---

**Edit**: Furthermore *chkrootkit* gives me this:

The following suspicious files and directories were found:

```
/usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable 
/usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v5.0/SupportedFrameworks/.NET Framework 4.6.xml 
/usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETFramework
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt5/uic/widget-plugins/.noinit 
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/widget-plugins/.noinit
/usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable
/usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETFramework
```

I guess that's a separate question? Or is this no issue at all? I don't know how to check if these files/directories are ok and needed.

**Edit**: Note I once also got warnings for "Checking for passwd file changes" and "Checking for group file changes" even though I didn't change any such afaik. An earlier and later scan showed no warnings - these just showed once. Any ideas?

Comment: `lwp-request` is supposed to be a Perl script, so that's an odd warning.

Comment: @derobert Do you get the same error then? Also the warning is imo about it having gotten replaced (to another perl script I guess) - not about it being a perl script. I copied its contents here: https://pastebin.com/bSLivGvz

Comment: I get the same warning on my Debian testing box. Your pastebin matches my copy of lwp-request too (though with line-ending changes, which I presume came from pastebin). So I suspect false alarm.

Answer (score 61):

`rkhunter` needs to know what package manager you are using.

Create or edit `/etc/rkhunter.conf.local` and add the following line:

```
PKGMGR=DPKG
```

If you are not on Debian or Ubuntu, then change `DPKG` for your actual package manager.

This way, `rkhunter` will know to expect those executables to be scripts, and not flag the false positive.

It will ensure that if the files are tampered with, then a new positive result will show.

Comment: Great; but why can't I set it to "APT-GET"? ([relevant question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/381967/233262)) And what's it using by default for checking the hashes if that's not DPKG for Debian? (`No value, or a value of 'NONE', indicates that no package manager is to be used.`)

Comment: @mYnDstrEAm rkhunter doesn't recognise apt as a package manager. dpkg is also a valid package manager on all systems that have apt (unless removed). I think the default value is RPM

Comment: @MacroMan The default value stated in the man page is `NONE`

Comment: The comments in rkhunter.conf state: "# NONE is the default for Debian as well, as running --propupd takes about 4 times longer when it's set to DPKG". See: https://github.com/crunchsec/rkhunter/blob/master/files/rkhunter.conf. It seems there is no need to set PKGMGR option

Comment: Dpkg is the package-manager, while apt(-get) is the frontend handling copying of packages from remote hosts, and automatic dependency downloads, and more. Same as Yum is a frontend to rpm.

Comment: rkhunter could have a simple installation script to detect the Linux distro and then set variables accordingly. It would save us a lot of time with false positives.

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned on: https://metacpan.org/pod/lwp-request, the lwp-request is a script that allows making http requests to web servers. It is not malicious and so the error can be ignored.

To suppress the error you need to allow the /usr/bin/lwp-request command to be used as a script. This can be done by adding the line:

```
SCRIPTWHITELIST=/usr/bin/lwp-request
```

To **/etc/rkhunter.conf** or **/etc/rkhunter.conf.local** file. See the **SCRIPTWHITELIST** option in the [rkhunter.conf configuration file](https://github.com/crunchsec/rkhunter/blob/master/files/rkhunter.conf)

This solution was mentioned on the [Linux Mint forums](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=238110)

Comment: And what if someone manages to replace lwp-request with a malicious script? Please be extra cautious using this suggestion. It leaves you vulnerable!

Comment: @MacroMan yeah but it's the only known way to get rkhunter to stop giving spurious warnings about these files ... So blame rkhunter.

Comment: @spinkus No, it's not. Let rkhunter know your package manager as per my answer and the warning will go away. Whitelisting something you don't control is just opening a vulnerability.