# Do package managers check the hashes of packages?

Tags: debian, security, package-management, hashsum

Do package managers such as Synaptic and Apper check the hashes of installed as well as updated/downloaded packages by comparing them to online databases?

Do they maybe even identify packages by their hashes?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is already answered on superuser: https://superuser.com/questions/990143/how-does-apt-get-checks-for-the-integrity-of-the-files-downloaded

Comment: [How is the authenticity of Debian packages guaranteed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/285635/86440) might also be relevant (I’m not suggesting it as a duplicate because of my gold hammer).