# Information on when packages were installed/updated by whom and coupling updates with rkhunter scans (rkhunter warnings)

Tags: debian, security, package-management, logs, rkhunter

So rkhunter gives me these warnings (in the logfile) beyond [this one (which seems to be a false positive)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373718/rkhunter-gives-me-a-warning-for-usr-bin-lwp-request-what-should-i-do-debi):

> Checking for passwd file changes              [ Warning ]
> Warning: User 'logcheck' has been added to the passwd file
>
> Info: Starting test name 'group_changes'
> Checking for group file changes                 [ Warning ]
> Warning: Changes found in the group file for group 'adm':
> User 'logcheck' has been added to the group
> Warning: Group 'logcheck' has been added to the group file.
>
> Checking for hidden files and directories       [ Warning ]
> Warning: Hidden directory found: /etc/.java

on one of my machines.

Another also shows me the warnings:

> Checking for passwd file changes                 [ Warning ]
> Warning: User 'clamav' has been added to the passwd file
> Warning: User 'geoclue' has been added to the passwd file
> Checking for group file changes                 [ Warning ]
> Warning: Group 'clamav' has been added to the group file
> Warning: Group 'geoclue' has been added to the group file

I guess these warnings are due to when I made the last earlier scan and due to package updates (e.g. openjde) and package-installations (clamtk)?

I'm not sure about geoclue and logcheck though as I can't remember installing logcheck and it doesn't display anything under "required by" in Apper.
Is there a way to display when packages were installed and updated and by whom?
Should package-updates and new installations maybe be coupled with other tools (too?) beyond rkhunter such as automatically doing some specific scan/update before a new installation or update etc?

Is there some way, tool or best practice to account for package updates and new installations?

I'm running a recently installed Debian 9.1 with KDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/var/log/apt/history.log*` contains logs of all `apt`’s activity, including the username of the user requesting the change (which is only useful if you use `sudo`, not `root` directly).

There already *is* some intergration between `rkhunter` and `apt`; see `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90rkhunter` on your system. If you want that to be enabled, you need to change `APT_AUTOGEN` in `/etc/default/rkhunter` to `true`.

You can also add your own pre- or post-installation jobs, *e.g.* to run a scan just before installation...

The “best practice” part of your question is too broad for this venue. Ultimately, some would argue you should only make changes to your systems using a tool such as Ansible, which provides its own logs of all changes.